# HBase chain MapReduce job with broadcasting smaller tables to all Mappers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am trying to write a chained MapReduce job on data present in HBase tables and need some help with the concept. I am not expecting people to provide code by pseudo code for this based on HBase's Java API would be nice.

In a nutshell, what I am trying to do is,

MapReduce Job 1:
Read data from two tables with no common row keys and create a summary out of them in the reducer. The output of the reducer is a Java Object containing the summary which has been serialized to byte code. I store this object in a temporary table in HBase.

MapReduce Job 2:
This is where I am having problems. I now need to read this summary object such that it is available in each mapper so that when I read data from a third (different) table, I can use this summary object to perform more calculations on the data I am reading from the third table.

I read about distributed cache and tried to implement it, but that doesn't seem to work out. I can provide more details in the form of edits if the need arises because I don't want to spam this question, right now, with details which might be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this might sound stupid, but if we have a really small table which we query, we can probably get away with reading the values using the HBase Java API (even in a MapReduce job) and then storing them in static variables. That way, we have to read those values only once per Mapper and it won't be much of an overhead.